# Why cannot Angular find this particular pipe?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is not the first custom Pipe I've made for Angular.

Here's the problem pipe:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { MaybeObservable } from '~/shared/maybe-async/maybe-observable';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({ name: 'maybeAsync', pure: false })
export class MaybeAsyncPipe implements PipeTransform {

    private wrappedAsyncPipe: AsyncPipe;

    public constructor (_ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.wrappedAsyncPipe = new AsyncPipe(_ref);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy (): void {
        this.wrappedAsyncPipe.ngOnDestroy();
    }

    public transform<T> (value: MaybeObservable<T>): T {
        if (value instanceof Observable) {
            return this.wrappedAsyncPipe.transform<T>(value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

And here's the module it's declared in:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaybeAsyncPipe } from './maybe-async.pipe';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [MaybeAsyncPipe],
    imports: [CommonModule],
    exports: [MaybeAsyncPipe],
    providers: [MaybeAsyncPipe],
})
export class MaybeAsyncModule { }
```

Which is imported into this other module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HorizontalScrollComponent } from './horizontal-scroll.component';
import { MaybeAsyncModule } from '~/shared/maybe-async/maybe-async.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [HorizontalScrollComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        MaybeAsyncModule,
    ],
    exports: [HorizontalScrollComponent],
})
export class HorizontalScrollModule {
}
```

And here's a fragment of an HTML template (not the only one, it makes no difference) where the pipe is finally being used:

```
<div
    *ngIf="customLeftArrow"
    class="hrzntl-scrl__arrow --left"
    (click)="scrollLeft()"
    [class.--active]="leftArrowIsActive$ | maybeAsync"
>
    <ng-content select="[id=customLeftArrow]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

It compiles and builds fine, the error I get in runtime is always some variation of:

```
Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'maybeAsync' could not be found ("
    class="hrzntl-scrl__arrow --left"
    (click)="scrollLeft()"
    [class.--active]="[ERROR ->]leftArrowIsActive$ | maybeAsync"
```

What am I missing? What might I try?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Pipe from the providers array of **`MaybeAsyncModule`**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [MaybeAsyncPipe],
    imports: [CommonModule],
    exports: [MaybeAsyncPipe],
    providers: [],
})
```

Comment: I will remove it because I am no longer [injecting the pipe into the component class.](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#the-pipetransform-interface) However, doing so does not fix the error.